# After insert trigger failing to join two tables with values inserted by a database transaction

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have 2 table *invoice_header table* and *invoice_line* table with details below:

1. **invoice_header colums** : invoice_id, customer_id
2. **invoice_line colums** : invoice_id, line_id ,item_id, quantity, line_flag
3. They are joined by the common column *invoice_id*
4. Values in these 2 tables are inserted using a *database transaction* by the application
5. Tables are on Microsoft SQL Server

I created a trigger on *invoice_line* to update *line_flag* to **zero** if *customer_id* is **10**. However the trigger is not working, I believe because it's failing to find a matching line in *invoice_header* since these two tables are inserted by a *database transaction* at the same time.

Below is the trigger

```
update                  invoice_line            
set                     line_flag = 0
from                    invoice_line l 
inner join              Inserted v  on v.line_id  = l.line_id 
inner join              invoice_header  h   on h.invoice_id = v.invoice_id
where                   h.customer_id = 10
```

If I don't join the tables, It works but updates all the lines.

I have also tried to rewrite the trigger on the *invoice_header* to update the lines but it's still not working.

**Is the a way to write an after insert trigger that joins tables inserted by database transaction?**

Answer (score 0):

> I believe because it's failing to find a matching line in
> invoice_header since these two tables are inserted by a database
> transaction at the same time.

This is not true; the data may still not be committed for "outsiders", but your own transaction can see the data it iself has already modified.

> the trigger is not working

While your question has some details, you don't mention why the trigger doesn't work. Do you mean it does nothing? Or is there an error? If so, which one?

```
update                  invoice_line
```

I think here's the cause for the error. You want to update `l` instead, since you have already aliased your table.

Comment: By "the  trigger not working", I mean the trigger is not updating invoice_line table when the tables are joined. So what might be the possible cause? This script works for tables updated separately

Comment: Did you read the last part of my answer?

Comment: Yes sir. So what do you propose I do?

Comment: change `update invoive_line` to `update l`

Comment: Thanks George, but doesn't seem to work